# Determine if two non-rectangles overlap in JS

Tags: javascript, svg, graphics, intersection

I have two html elements (in my case they are SVG path elements). Each of these has a different stroke width. Is there any way to determine if two of these paths overlap? I have tried using the npm [path intersection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-intersection) library, but it doesn't allow me to specify a width. Also, the results are approximate, but I need more exact data.

I don't need to calculate the actual intersection area, or coordinates. I just need to know if an intersection occurs between these two paths with definite widths. Is there a solution?

edit:
here is an example to demonstrate something i want

```html
<svg xmls="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="p1" d="M10,10 C20,30, 50,70, 100,100" stroke-width="3" stroke='black'></path>
  <path id="p2" d="M20,0 Q200,30,0,100" stroke-width="5" stroke="red"></path>
</svg>
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

in javascript, i have something like this:

```
let p1 = document.getElementById("p1"), p2 = document.getElementById("p2");

if (p1 intersects/overlaps with p2) {
  //run some code
}
```

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr0Ey.png)

it produces the above, which i classify as an intersection, as the paths themselves overlap

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdfED.png)
here, i produced the same lines, but one is shifted. I do not classify this as an overlap

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: get the bounding boxes and see if they overlap i.e. call getBBox. You can expand the boxes by half the stroke width to account for the stroke.

Comment: @Robert Longson, you were involved in this years ago, what is the status on ``CheckIntersection`` https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_svgsvgelement_checkintersection  Has Mozilla shelved this?

Comment: @decpk I have edited to include an example of what I want, Thanks.

Comment: For JavaScript code peek at: http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm

Comment: @RobertLongson Hi, from what I understand getBBox returns a rectangle, so checking them would cause intersection when only the boxes do. Is there a way around?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you, I am having a look now.

Comment: A way around what?