# SVG path intersections respecting stroke width and stroke fill

Tags: javascript, svg, graphics

I recently asked another question about SVG intersection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72837002/determine-if-two-non-rectangles-overlap-in-js), to which I got some good answers. But I am now looking for a method to find if two paths intersect that respects stroke fill, and stroke size.

In my example, I am making an application for handwriting. I have an erase tool that can change its stroke width.

[example 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7NxC.png)
The red line in this photo represents the eraser, and the black line represents a stroke i want to erase. using the [path intersection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-intersection) library and the [methods from here (line intersects with absolute path)](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm) the intersection is not detected. Is there an easy way to do this?

[example 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZrmi.png) I have a scissor tool in my application. The highlighted blue area intersects with the inner path because the fill overlaps with it. How do I determine if this type of event occurs? For another example, I also consider the below an intersection:
[example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SbEv.png)

My example code is very simple. I just have an SVG element with N paths inside of it. I want to have a script such that I can loop through all the paths and determine if any 2 intersect. If possible, I want to attach an event listener to each path to determine when it intersects with another. Is there an easy algorithm or solution for this?

Comment: Write both text to canvas with 50% opacity for each and then scan the canvas and see if there are any pixel that indicate overlap